# How does the day/night cycle in Bravely Default work?

Tags: bravely-default

Bravely Default has a Day/Night cycle that affects the appearance of towns, dungeons and the overworld, as well as certain story events and monster that appears in the overworld.

It is sometimes desirable to change the time to day or night, for instance, to farm certain monsters or to advance the story, or to view the time. Is there any way of doing this, other than sleeping in an inn, which will always set the time back to day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, setting time *immediately* to day can be done only by sleeping in the inn (also some cutscenes, but since those aren't repeatable, they aren't really viable).

But the time of day changes with passing time in the real world, not number of steps. So you can just leave the game on for a minute or two (the days pass pretty quickly in Luxendarc) and voilá - you have your night. Or day. Whichever you want, really, just wait a bit more.